# Car radio that I can develop for

Tags: car, audio, software

Is there a such thing as a car radio that I can develop software for? It can run Windows or Linux OS. I have a radio that currently runs Windows CE but I can't find an easy way to load any software onto it.

Comment: Check out the carpc website it's more involved than just installing a radio but you can run whatever os and frontend you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very common to use small android tablets in double-DIN slots, and you then get all the fun of Android development.